# Shared Connection to host Closed on running Ansible playbook as unprivileged user?

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible v2.9.2 and recently I am facing issues using the npm ansible module as it is giving me shared connection to host closed errors. I have tried using both python2 and 3 and the results were the same. Below is the doc containing my error and playbook as well please have a look.

link: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iaNMIjR3EVFYVvSoJEPTmjhSrDsnfZc5VCvUUamdKps/edit?usp=sharing

> fatal: [1.0.3.99]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 1.0.3.99 closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n File \"/var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1577345183.7290096-173113890020428/AnsiballZ_npm.py\", line 114, in \r\n _ansiballz_main()\r\n File \"/var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1577345183.7290096-173113890020428/AnsiballZ_npm.py\", line 106, in _ansiballz_main\r\n invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\r\n File \"/var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1577345183.7290096-173113890020428/AnsiballZ_npm.py\", line 49, in invoke_module\r\n imp.load_module('**main**', mod, module, MOD_DESC)\r\n File \"/tmp/ansible_npm_payload_6EJdAk/**main**.py\", line 310, in \r\n File \"/tmp/ansible_npm_payload_6EJdAk/**main**.py\", line 287, in main\r\n File \"/tmp/ansible_npm_payload_6EJdAk/**main**.py\", line 200, in list\r\n File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/json/**init**.py\", line 339, in loads\r\n return _default_decoder.decode(s)\r\n File \"/usr/lib…

Ansible Playbook:

```
- hosts: all
  remote_user: abhinav
  become: yes
  tasks:
   - name: npm command
     npm:
        path: /data/codebase/test/api
        executable: /home/test/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.0/bin/npm
        state: present
     become_user: test
     become: yes
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is [becoming an unprivileged user](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#risks-of-becoming-an-unprivileged-user)

> When both the connection user and the become_user are unprivileged, the module file is written as the user that Ansible connects as, but the file needs to be readable by the user Ansible is set to become. In this case, Ansible makes the module file world-readable ... Starting in Ansible 2.1, **Ansible defaults to issuing an error if it cannot execute securely with become**."

See [Ways to resolve this include:](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#risks-of-becoming-an-unprivileged-user)

- Use [pipelining](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-pipelining) `pipelining = true`
- Install POSIX.1e filesystem acl support on the managed host.
- Avoid becoming an unprivileged user.

Comment: i tried the 1st step but it didn't work either, i included this flag in the ansible.cfg but it still gives the same error.